# SQL query to display before specified date

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, date

I am trying to get the sum of all sale prices before a specified date, I have tried the following.

```
SELECT SUM (Sale_Price), Sale_Date
FROM sales
GROUP BY Sale_Price, Sale_Date
WHERE Sale_Date < '2015-10-12';
```

However I keep getting "SQL command not properly ended". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the sum for all the dates, then you would use:

```
SELECT SUM(Sale_Price)
FROM sales
WHERE Sale_Date < DATE '2015-10-12';
```

You only need the `GROUP BY` if you want one row for each dae.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Sale_Date, SUM(Sale_Price)
FROM sales 
WHERE Sale_Date < DATE '2015-10-12'
GROUP BY Sale_Date
```

Comment: "literal does not match format string" 

I am using the DATE format in the DB, entered in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Try `DATE '2015-10-12'`